# Regex Match Paragraph Pattern

Tags: regex

I am trying to match a paragraph pattern and I am having trouble.

The pattern is:

```
[image.gif]
some words, usually a few lines

name

emailaddress<mailto:theemailaddress@mail.com>
```

I tried matching everything between the `gif image` and the `<mailto:` but this happens multiple times in the file meaning I get a bad result.

I tried it with this

```
(?<=\[image.gif\].*?(\[image.gif\])).*?(?=<mailto:)
```

Is there a way to use Regex to match the general layout of a paragraph?

Comment: You test for `[image.gif\]` which does not occur in your sample input. Could you correct your question?

Comment: Slow `(?s)(?<=\[image\.gif\]).*?(?=<mailto:)`, faster `(?s)\[image\.gif\](.*?)(?=<mailto:)`, fastest `(?s)\[image\.gif\](.*?)<mailto:`

Answer (score 1):

"the general layout of a paragraph" needs a better definition. Given the lack of an input plus expected output, I'm having to guess what you want here.  I'm also guessing that you will accept any language.  Here's `perl`, almost certainly not a language you're familiar with.

Assumed input:

```
do not match this line
[image.gif]
some words, usually a few lines

Bobert McBobson

emailaddress<mailto:bobertmb@example.com>
don't match this line either
[image.gif]
another few words
on another few lines

Bobina Robertsdaughter

emailaddress<mailto:bobinard@example.info>
this line is also not for matching
```

Expected output:

```
[image.gif]
some words, usually a few lines

Bobert McBobson

emailaddress<mailto:bobertmb@example.com>
---
[image.gif]
another few words
on another few lines

Bobina Robertsdaughter

emailaddress<mailto:bobinard@example.info>
```

Solution using `perl`:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl -n007

my $sep = "";
while (/(\[image\.gif\].*?<mailto:[^>]*>(\r)?\n)/gms) {
  print $sep . $1;
  $sep = "---$2\n";
}
```

`perl` is the king of regex languages; many would say that's all it is good for.  Here, we use the `-n007` option to tell it to read the entire contents of each file and run the code on it as the default variable.

`$sep` starts blank because there's nothing to separate until the second match.

Then we loop over each block of text that matches the regex:

- matches a literal `[image.gif]`
- then matches as little content following that as possible
- then matches a literal `<mailto:` and continues until the next `>`
- then captures the line break (including optional support for DOS line endings)
- ([see full regex explanation and example at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/dQ0dA5/1))

We then print the match and finally set the separator to three dashes and a line break (DOS line endings added when needed).

Now you can run it:

```
$ perl answer.pl input.txt
[image.gif]
some words, usually a few lines

Bobert McBobson

emailaddress<mailto:bobertmb@example.com>
---
[image.gif]
another few words
on another few lines

Bobina Robertsdaughter

emailaddress<mailto:bobinard@example.info>
```